# how can i get dates on saturday and sunday between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am very weak with browser end script like javascript , as i am a php developer. I need to get the dates on Saturday and Sunday. I have found many answer to calculate the count but have not found a way to get dates on Saturday and Sunday .I have try these:

```
Date.prototype.endOfWeek = function(){
  return new Date( 
      this.getFullYear(), 
      this.getMonth(), 
      this.getDate() + 6 - this.getDay() 
  );
};

var now = new Date();

// returns next saturday; and returns saturday if it is saturday today.
alert(now.endOfWeek() );
```

it returns me only the next saturday date .Please help me to get this

I also tried this , but it returns me the count

```
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
        var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
        if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
        var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
        var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
        if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

        // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
        iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

        if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
          iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
                    alert(iDateDiff);
        } else {
          iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
        }

        iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

        return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
    }


alert(calcBusinessDays(new Date("August 11, 2010 11:13:00"),new Date("August 16, 2010 11:13:00")));
```

Comment: first function returns Date object for next saturday. do you want to return array contains two Date object of both saturday and sunday?

Comment: Do you want to return **all** saturdays and sundays between two dates, just the next weekend, or what ?

Answer (score 4):

> how can i get dates on saturday and sunday between two dates in
>   javascript

Something like this would return all saturdays and sundays between two given days

```
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) {
    if (dDate1 > dDate2) return false;
    var date  = dDate1;
    var dates = [];

    while (date < dDate2) {
        if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) dates.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
    }

    return dates;
}
```

```js
var d1 = new Date(2015, 3, 3);
var d2 = new Date(2015, 5, 3);

function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) {
    if (dDate1 > dDate2) return false;
    var date  = dDate1;
    var dates = [];

    while (date < dDate2) {
        if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) dates.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
    }
    
    return dates;
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(calcBusinessDays(d1,d2), null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: displaying "2015-04-03T18:30:00.000Z",
    "2015-04-04T18:30:00.000Z", as sat sunday but actual its friday saturday

Comment: Indeed it does here, when I try it in a fiddle it shows april 4th and 5th instead, so it does work, and there's no way `getDay` would be `0` or `6` on a friday, so something strange is happening in the snippet here ?